# Embedded Google Spreadsheet as a iFrame (two scroll bars)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sites

I embedded a single sheet (as a iframe) in the webpage (Google website).
How to to leave (to show) only one scroll bar if required?

[image]

Comment: How did you made the embedding? Are using the new Google Sites or the Old Google Sites?

Comment: I use Old Google Sites.

Answer (score 0):

Make the iframe the same height and width as the google sheet. Also, You can right click the column headers and rows in the google sheet to delete unwanted rows and headers to make the sheet size smaller.

```
<iframe src="/default.asp" width="200" height="200"></iframe>
```